# Custom Footnote Key/ID

Tags: macros, footnotes

I would like footnotes to not show numbers but rather whatever text I want. So something like this:

```
Here is my text. No numbers appear here even though there are footnotes embedded all throughout. 

----------

1:1 Footnote with custom key '1:1"
1:2 Another footnote with custom key.
2:4 Not necessarily covering every combination, so I need to be able skip some.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `\Footnote` and a modified version of `\Footnotemark` from the [`nccfoots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccfoots) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccfoots}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\Footnotemark}[1]{\NCC@makefnmark{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example
Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
 test text test text test text test text test text test text
 test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
 test text test text test text test text test text

\Footnote{1:1}{This is the first footnote}
\Footnote{1:2}{This is the second footnote}
\Footnote{2:4}{This is yet another footnote with a different marker}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, but it still needs to be tied to the text in some way so that it will always be on the same page. Any way to do that?

Comment: @Dan I don't understand; what do you want to always be on the same page? If you place the `\Footnote` commands appropriately, then the footnote text will appear on a desired page.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll give it a shot.