# Create a new command that makes a footnote

Tags: macros, footnotes

Following some [earlier code I've been given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173060/9077), I'm creating macros for meta-data about my papers (such as title, author, etc.). Now I'd like to create my own `\thanks` macro that should follow the title. Yet in this case the result is simply that the content of `\mythanks` is printed after the title, instead of creating a footnote. How can I make it produce a footnote instead?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\@mytitle{} % create macro for title
    \newcommand\mytitle[1]{\renewcommand\@mytitle{#1}}
    \newcommand\@mythanks{\footnote} % create macro for thanks note
    \newcommand\mythanks[1]{\renewcommand\@mythanks{#1}}
    \newcommand\@myauthor{} % create macro for author
    \newcommand\myauthor[1]{\renewcommand\@myauthor{#1}}
    \newcommand{\articletitle}{%
        \begingroup%
            \centering%
            \fontsize{18bp}{18bp}\selectfont%
            \@mytitle\@mythanks\par%
            \vspace{\baselineskip}%
            \fontsize{14bp}{14bp}\selectfont%
            \@myauthor\par%
            \fontsize{12bp}{12bp}\selectfont%
            \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
        \endgroup}
\makeatother

\mytitle{This is my title}
\mythanks{These are my acknowledgements}
\myauthor{This is the author}

\AtBeginDocument{\articletitle}

\begin{document}
I start writing here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textsuperscript{}` is what you want?

Comment: @Sigur No, I'd like a footnote.

Comment: So you want to insert some symbol as superscript and also the text as a footnote? What is the problem with `\footnote{\@mythanks}`?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, that's right. Actually, I want the symbol to be a star and not the numeral 1, and then I actually don't want that symbol to appear after the title at all, but _only_ in the footnote (I wanted to wait and open separate questions about those things, since I like to limit my questions to one thing at a time - that's more helpful for later visitors).

Comment: This could help you to create a footnote without numbers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127258/14757

Comment: @Sigur Thanks, that's useful, but I would still need to figure out how to define my `\mythanks` as this alternative `\Footnote`.

Comment: the document class `amsart` contains code for "thanks" footnotes associated with the author.  they are unnumbered, but changing that to include a star shouldn't be too problematic.

Comment: Should `\mythanks` behave as the standard `\thanks`? I mean, besides giving you a footnote, should it be used *inside* the `\mytitle` command?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Actually, I always strongly disliked the placement of the standard `\thanks` command inside `\title`. So I'd prefer to do `\mytitle{} \mythanks{} \myauthor{}` as above.

Comment: @Sverre I see. My answer is useless then. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\@mytitle{} % create macro for title
    \newcommand\mytitle[1]{\renewcommand\@mytitle{#1}}
    \newcommand\@mythanks{} % create macro for thanks note
    \newcommand\mythanks[1]{\renewcommand\@mythanks{%
      \gdef\@thefnmark{*}\@footnotetext{#1}}
    }
    \newcommand\@myauthor{} % create macro for author
    \newcommand\myauthor[1]{\renewcommand\@myauthor{#1}}
    \newcommand{\articletitle}{%
        \begingroup%
            \centering%
            \fontsize{18bp}{18bp}\selectfont%
            \@mytitle%
            \@mythanks%
            \par
            \vspace{\baselineskip}%
            \fontsize{14bp}{14bp}\selectfont%
            \@myauthor\par%
            \fontsize{12bp}{12bp}\selectfont%
            \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
        \endgroup}
\makeatother

\mytitle{This is my title}
\mythanks{These are my acknowledgements}
\myauthor{This is the author}

\AtBeginDocument{\articletitle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no footnotemarker in the footnote here.

Comment: Ow, sorry, I swapped what you want. I put the symbol in the wrong place. Edited. You can change the symbol, if you wish.

Comment: Add `\lipsum` to the document, and you'll see a problem.

Comment: @Sverre, please, see it now.